# What is correct way of finding path between 2 nodes without getting warnings in neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am currently working with `neo4j` and I need to find path between 2 nodes in large graph. I am using this cypher query:

```
MATCH p=(acq:Acquisition {id:'1'})-[r*]->(ecs:ExternalCommunicationService {id:'1'})
RETURN p
```

Everything works as expected (query returns path of any length between nodes) but I am getting warning message displayed bellow:

> Warning: This feature is deprecated and will be removed in future versions. Binding relationships to a list in a variable length pattern is deprecated.

In official [documentation](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/clauses/match/) is used same pattern with `*`.

What is the correct way of finding paths of any lengths between nodes without getting any warning(without using deprecated syntax) ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Binding relationships to a list in a variable length pattern is deprecated since [3.2.0-rc1](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/wiki/Neo4j-3.2-changelog#320-rc1).

According this [pull request](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/pull/9160) Cypher queries like:

```
MATCH (n)-[rs*]-() RETURN rs
```

will generate a warning and the canonical way to write the same query is:

```
MATCH p=(n)-[*]-() RETURN relationships(p) AS rs
```

Since you are not using the `r` variable in your query you can simply remove it from the query and the warning will disappear. This way:

```
MATCH p=(acq:Acquisition {id:'1'})-[*]->(ecs:ExternalCommunicationService {id:'1'})
RETURN p
```

Comment: Thank you, this is right solution to my question :)

Answer (score 2):

All that means is that is a future release, your use of `r` in your pattern will no longer be permitted. Your query will need to look like this or it will break in a future release. Since you are not directly trying to use `r` in your results it should no problem for you to remove it.

```
MATCH p=(acq:Acquisition {id:'1'})-[*]->(ecs:ExternalCommunicationService {id:'1'})
RETURN p
```

You could always get the relationships using the `relationships(p)` to return a collection of relationships from the path if you needed to do something with them after the match.

Depending on the nature of your graph (size and complexity) though your query may become unwieldy because it is virtually unconstrained except for the ending node and the direction.  There are a number of ways you could make it safer.

### 1 - Use shortestPath

You could use `shortestPath` or `allShortestPaths`

```
MATCH p=allShortestPaths((acq:Acquisition {id:'1'})-[*]->(ecs:ExternalCommunicationService {id:'1'}))
RETURN p
```

### 2 - Limit the Depth

You could add a limit on the depth of the match. It could be fixed

```
MATCH p=(acq:Acquisition {id:'1'})-[*10]->(ecs:ExternalCommunicationService {id:'1'})
RETURN p
```

or a range

```
MATCH p=(acq:Acquisition {id:'1'})-[*5..10]->(ecs:ExternalCommunicationService {id:'1'})
RETURN p
```

### 3 - Add Relationship TYPE

You could add one or more labels to reduce the potential number of paths you match.  That can be used in conjunction with the depth parameters.

```
MATCH p=(acq:Acquisition {id:'1'})-[:TYPE_A|TYPE_B*5..10]->(ecs:ExternalCommunicationService {id:'1'})
RETURN p
```

### 4 - Use APOC

You could use APOC procedures.

Comment: Thank you for additional options in creating queries. They will definitely become handy when my graph will get bigger